# Trouble with Bearer Token Authorization via Authorization Code (PKCE) in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I've been trying to replicate the PKCE Authorization Code flow from Postman to JMeter, and I've encountered an issue. Specifically, when I make a request to */connect/token* in JMeter, the response I receive is **{"error":"invalid_client"}**.

To provide some context, I have a collection set up in Postman where I'm using the PKCE method for authorization. Everything seems to work smoothly until I reach the final step involving the */connect/token* request. When I attempt to perform the same steps in JMeter, I encounter this problem.

Here's a summary of my actions:

1. I successfully imported the relevant requests from Postman into JMeter.
2. I've verified that all the required parameters are correctly included in the */connect/token* request.
3. Other requests within the collection, which don't pertain to token exchange, function properly in JMeter.
4. I've meticulously cross-checked the authorization code and other related parameters to ensure they match between Postman and JMeter.

Despite my best efforts, I consistently receive the **{"error":"invalid_client"}** response when executing the */connect/token* request in JMeter. It appears that there might be subtle differences between how Postman and JMeter handle this request that I haven't yet identified.

[JMeter - Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdVp1.jpg)

I've noticed something interesting about the headers in the */connect/token* request using Postman. The User-Agent is set as *PostmanRuntime/7.32.3*. I tried adjusting the headers to match those in Postman, but I'm getting a POST 302 response instead of 200. This might be due to the request automation in Postman after logging into the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you can successfully obtain the token using Postman you should be able to record the flow using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

[Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/installation/proxy/)

[image]

and run your collection. JMeter will generate appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and [HTTP Header Managers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

Once you perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) of dynamic parameters you should be able to get the token in JMeter as well.

Comment: I don't have any issues with the collection itself (I've manually used the bearer token extracted from Postman). My struggle lies in generating the token within JMeter. I'm wondering why replicating a 1:1 set of requests from Postman during the authentication process works seamlessly one after another (connect/authorize -> SSO -> Login -> OTP -> Callback), yet it's only at the critical point (connect/token), the most important one, that it throws an error.